# extrafont R package not changing font in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, extrafont

Downloaded the font through the [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman) as a TTF file.

Each font of the Latin Modern Roman was installed into the designated font Windows folder:

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
library(ggplot2) 

font_import(pattern = "lmroman*")
> Found FontName for 0 fonts 

loadfonts(device = "win")
> LM Roman 10 already registered with windowsFonts().
LM Roman Caps 10 already registered with windowsFonts().
LM Roman Demi 10 already registered with windowsFonts().
LM Roman Dunhill 10 already registered with windowsFonts().
LM Roman Slanted 10 already registered with windowsFonts().

par(family = "LM Roman 10") # No message; as if loaded in correctly
```

When running the `theme()` code below it does not change the font. It keeps it as the default text font with R `ggplot2` plots:

```
plot1 + 
     geom_bar() + 
     theme(text = element_text(size = 10, family = "LM Roman 10"))
```

I tried everything above and was expecting the font to change in the final bar plot.